# get Facebook friends first_name without second api call

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova

In my Ionic project, I'm running this fb javascript api call:

```
$cordovaFacebook.api("me/friends", ["user_friends"])
                .then(
                    function(success) {
                      console.log("SPLASHCTRL: FB: GOT FBAPP FRIENDS SUCCESFULLY: " + success.data.length);

                       $scope.fbAppFriends = success.data;
                       console.log('SPLASHCTRL: FB: SETTING LOADING TO FALSE');

                       $scope.loadingFbFriends = false;
                    // success
                   }, 
                   function (error) {
                    console.log('SPLASHCTRL: FB: ERROR GETTING FRIENDS' + JSON.stringify(error));

                  }
                );
```

which works, but only returns friend's name, id... , not containing his **first_name**.

Would there be a way to require this directly in the data response, or am i supposed to use the api for every friend again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy solution in one call:

```
me/friends?fields=first_name,last_name
```